# Thread em Webbrowser c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, navegador-de-internet

Preciso utilizar uma thread que consiga trabalhar junto com um webbrowser em c#.Ela só precisa executar o comando, mas como é um componente visual não estou conseguindo. Abaixo detalho algumas tentativas e exemplos que achei. Se alguém tiver uma luz ou outra ideia, por favor comentem!! Obrigado

Baseado no artigo original disponível em https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269800/webbrowser-control-in-a-new-thread.

```
      private void runBrowserThread(Uri url)
      {
          var th = new Thread(() => {
              var br = new WebBrowser();
              br.DocumentCompleted += browser_DocumentCompleted;
              br.Navigate(url);
              // aqui ao invés de navegar até a URL, preciso montar meu html
              br.DocumentText =  "<html><body></body></html>"
              Application.Run();
          });

          th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
          th.Start();
      }

      void browser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e) 
      {
          var br = sender as WebBrowser;
          if (br.Url == e.Url) 
          {
               Console.WriteLine("Natigated to {0}", e.Url);
               Application.ExitThread();   // Stops the thread
          }
      }
```

Estou tendo o erro

> Não é possível usar o objeto COM que foi separado do seu RCW subjacente." e threw an exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.InvalidComObjectException

Comment: porque manda o comando Navigate, e depois irá definir o HTML na mão ?

Comment: Testei seu código e compilou tranquilo. só observei que na linha: `br.DocumentText` tá faltando o ; no final. Tá usando windows Forms? WPF?

Comment: Aqui também funcionou tranquilo. Só tirei a linha `br.DocumentText = "<html><body></body></html>"` que além de estar faltando `;` anula o comando `navigate` e no evento sempre aparece `about:blank`

Comment: Obrigado pelas respostas pessoal. O exemplo acima peguei no tópico que citei. Como comentado ao invés do navigate preciso montar o hmtl. Só deixei para ser como um auxílio. Aquele html é só um teste, o que preciso executar é um pouco maior. Podem ignorar o br.Navigate(url);